# Center the \not to the letter

Tags: symbols, relation-symbols

I searched but I didn't find anything: does anyone know how to center the \not{A} to the letter instead of typing it a little before?

Comment: Well, I think `\not` is supposed to work with `\mathrel` objects, of which `A` is not.  Thus, a roundabout way to get that is `B\mathord{\not\mathrel{A}}C`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I said in my earlier comment, I think `\not` is supposed to work with `\mathrel` objects, of which A is not (it is `\mathord`).

With that in mind, here are two possible ways.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
B\mathord{\not\mathrel{A}}C
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
B\stackengine{0pt}{A}{/}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}C
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `slashed`. In the example, the default placement (as ordinary symbol) is used. Then it's shown how to fine tune the position of the slash (experiment yourself) and to make the symbol a relation symbol.

Of course, the `\declareslash` instruction will go in the document preamble, when you have chosen the final parameters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{slashed}

\begin{document}

$\slashed{A}$

\declareslashed{}{/}{0.05}{0}{A}

$\slashed{A}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This may be much simpler

```
\usepackage{centernot}
\begin{document}

$\centernot{\infty}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't know that package, _esker_. Regarding the question, it should be `$\centernot{A}$` instead of `$\centernot{\infty}$`